# what is the root password of telepresence in kubernetes remote debugging

Tags: kubernetes, telepresence

I am using Telepresence to remote debugging the Kubernetes cluster, and I am log in cluster using command

```bash
telepresence
```

but when I want to install some software in the telepresence pod

```bash
sudo apt-get install wget
```

and I did not know the password of telepresence pod, so what should I do to install software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could using this script to login pod as root:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xe

POD=$(kubectl describe pod "$1")
NODE=$(echo "$POD" | grep -m1 Node | awk -F'/' '{print $2}')
CONTAINER=$(echo "$POD" | grep -m1 'Container ID' | awk -F 'docker://' '{print $2}')

CONTAINER_SHELL=${2:-bash}

set +e

ssh -t "$NODE" sudo docker exec --user 0 -it "$CONTAINER" "$CONTAINER_SHELL"

if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]; then
  set +x
  echo 'SSH into pod failed. If you see an error message similar to "executable file not found in $PATH", please try:'
  echo "$0 $1 sh"
fi
```

login like this:

```
./login-k8s-pod.sh flink-taskmanager-54d85f57c7-wd2nb
```